# Passing a related field ID to an API endpoint in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I will try my best to make this easy to understand:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data_sheet": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/store/data_sheets/EN_DS_MVS6300-LV_Datasheet.pdf",
        "module": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data_sheet": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/store/data_sheets/EN_DS_MVS6300-LV_Datasheet_Pck5SQy.pdf",
        "module": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "data_sheet": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/store/data_sheets/Trina_670Wp_from_Gamechange_abXvA3H.pdf",
        "module": 5
    }
]
```

Basically, if I can go to an endpoint using the id like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/1/`. Result would be this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "data_sheet": "http://127.0.0.1:27038/static/media/store/data_sheets/EN_DS_MVS6300-LV_Datasheet.pdf",
    "module": 3
}
```

But am unable to achieve the same using the module id. say for instance: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/5/` results in this:

```
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

the module happens to be a related field I have no idea how I can use it and pass it as part of the queryset.

**My models.py:**

```
class Cable(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Cable ({self.tag}, {self.manufacturer}, {self.model})"

    def supports_arch(self, arch):
        return self.architecture[arch] == '1'


class CableDataSheet(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Cable, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='data_sheets')
    data_sheet = models.FileField(
        upload_to='store/data_sheets',
        validators=[
            validate_file_size,
            FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'jpg', 'png'])
        ]
    )
```

**my views.py:**

```
class CableViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'options']
    serializer_class = CableSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    permission_classes = [IsApplicationOrAdmin]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Cable.objects.all()
        arch = self.request.query_params.get('arch', False)
        if arch in architectures:
            return queryset.filter(architecture__regex=arch_regex[architectures.index(arch)])
        return queryset

class CableSheets(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'options']
    serializer_class = CableDataSheetSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = CableDataSheet.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

**My serializers:**

```
class CableDataSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    module = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='id'
    )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        cable_id = self.context['cable_id']
        return CableDataSheet.objects.create(cable_id=cable_id, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = CableDataSheet
        fields = ['id', 'data_sheet', 'module']
    


class CableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    data_sheets = CableDataSheetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cable
        fields = [
            'id','data_sheets'
        ]
```

Sorry if I made the explanation too long, just trying to get across my question. I would appreciate if anyone could help

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/5/ is asking for the CableDataSheet of id 5. Given what you provided, i guess it does not exist, hence 404 error.

If you want to get all CableDataSheet tied to the module of id 5, your request should look like http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/?module=5.
You should be able to filter by module in your get_queryset method as you already did with the "architecture" field (make you the client provided a number otherwise django will raise an error)

You should take a moment to read about REST API conventions https://restfulapi.net/

Comment: Tried doing as you said by using http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/?module=5. I didn't actaully raise an error but didnt filter the results either. no idea what's goin on. The page just showed all datasheets instead. Is there maybe a probem on how I set up the views?

Comment: Did the get_queryset method received the query parameter ?

Comment: I don't think it did.. That's the whole thing with my question, am not entirely sure that my queryset if the problem is with my queryset or somewhere else, thus why I put my views.py here for reference

Comment: you can always declare a list(self, request) method in your viewset if you feel it is too much of a blackbox. The list method will be called for request on 127.0.0.1:8000/store/cable_datasheets/

Comment: I will give it a try and see how it works out, thanks